# Debian: logging out causes services to become unavailable

Tags: debian, login, services, logout

I run Bullseye with XFCE on a Dell Inpiron 5567.

I have two users on this system: mine and a Guest; whenever I log out from whichever was logged in first and log in again, [b]even as my user[/b], pulseaudio doesn't start automatically and apart from "Log out", all other options in `xfce4-session-logout` become unavailable; I attach a link to a screencap of this (I got "Internal server error 500" when trying to upload the image to this post). In the image you can see what happens when I run `xfce4-session-logout`and the audio mixer trying to connect to Pulseaudio; this is just after logging back in with my main user.

My concern is not that it only happens when I log in as the guest user, but also if I log out and back in as my main user. None of this, of course, happens on CLI mode.

Here's the output of cat /var/log/auth.log, because I do not know where else to look in order to know what is happening.

```
Mar 15 10:59:39 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 10:59:39 monk xscreensaver[69256]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 10:59:44 monk xscreensaver[69257]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 10:59:44 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Mar 15 11:04:09 monk su: (to nobody) root on none
Mar 15 11:04:09 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Mar 15 11:04:10 monk systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Mar 15 11:04:10 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 15 11:04:10 monk su: (to nobody) root on none
Mar 15 11:04:10 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Mar 15 11:04:10 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 15 11:04:10 monk su: (to nobody) root on none
Mar 15 11:04:10 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Mar 15 11:06:05 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 15 11:06:16 monk systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 15 11:17:01 monk CRON[70318]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 11:17:01 monk CRON[70318]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 11:30:01 monk CRON[70654]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 11:30:01 monk CRON[70654]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 12:02:16 monk systemd-logind[787]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event10 (30:C0:1B:9E:31:AA)
Mar 15 12:17:01 monk CRON[71238]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 12:17:01 monk CRON[71238]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 12:30:01 monk CRON[71549]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 12:30:01 monk CRON[71549]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 13:17:01 monk CRON[72233]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 13:17:01 monk CRON[72233]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 13:30:01 monk CRON[72398]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 13:30:01 monk CRON[72398]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 14:17:01 monk CRON[73706]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 14:17:01 monk CRON[73706]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 14:22:53 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 14:22:53 monk xscreensaver[73753]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 14:22:58 monk xscreensaver[73760]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 14:22:58 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Mar 15 14:30:01 monk CRON[73915]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 14:30:01 monk CRON[73915]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 15:17:01 monk CRON[75560]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 15:17:01 monk CRON[75560]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 15:30:02 monk CRON[76263]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 15:30:02 monk CRON[76263]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 15:34:33 monk dbus-daemon[759]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.28" (uid=1000 pid=1175 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no ") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.3" (uid=0 pid=756 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd ")
Mar 15 16:17:01 monk CRON[77140]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 16:17:01 monk CRON[77140]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 16:22:17 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 16:22:17 monk xscreensaver[77179]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 16:22:21 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): conversation failed
Mar 15 16:22:21 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): auth could not identify password for [guajardo]
Mar 15 16:30:01 monk CRON[77247]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 16:30:01 monk CRON[77247]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 16:31:05 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 16:31:05 monk xscreensaver[77253]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 16:31:11 monk xscreensaver[77263]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 16:31:11 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Mar 15 17:17:01 monk CRON[78550]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 17:17:01 monk CRON[78550]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 17:30:01 monk CRON[78669]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 17:30:01 monk CRON[78669]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 17:43:03 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 17:43:03 monk xscreensaver[78804]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 17:43:10 monk xscreensaver[78814]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 17:43:10 monk unix_chkpwd[78814]: password check failed for user (guajardo)
Mar 15 17:43:10 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty=:0.0 ruser= rhost=  user=guajardo
Mar 15 17:43:12 monk xscreensaver[2070]: FAILED LOGIN 1 ON DISPLAY ":0.0", FOR "guajardo"
Mar 15 17:43:14 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 17:43:14 monk xscreensaver[78815]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 17:43:23 monk xscreensaver[78818]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 17:43:23 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Mar 15 17:49:01 monk CRON[79103]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 17:49:01 monk CRON[79103]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 18:17:01 monk CRON[79800]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 18:17:01 monk CRON[79800]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 18:20:54 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 18:20:58 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 18:20:58 monk su: (to root) guajardo on pts/0
Mar 15 18:20:58 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar 15 18:22:01 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 18:30:01 monk CRON[80317]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 18:30:01 monk CRON[80317]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 19:17:01 monk CRON[81934]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 19:17:01 monk CRON[81934]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 19:18:20 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 19:18:23 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 19:18:23 monk su: (to root) guajardo on pts/1
Mar 15 19:18:23 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar 15 19:19:48 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 19:22:03 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 19:22:07 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 19:22:07 monk su: (to root) guajardo on pts/1
Mar 15 19:22:07 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar 15 19:22:34 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 19:30:01 monk CRON[82649]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 19:30:01 monk CRON[82649]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 20:17:01 monk CRON[83124]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 20:17:01 monk CRON[83124]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 20:30:01 monk CRON[83257]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 20:30:01 monk CRON[83257]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 21:17:01 monk CRON[83765]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 21:17:01 monk CRON[83765]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 21:30:01 monk CRON[83912]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 21:30:01 monk CRON[83912]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 22:17:01 monk CRON[84393]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 22:17:01 monk CRON[84393]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 22:30:01 monk CRON[84704]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 22:30:01 monk CRON[84704]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 23:08:48 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 23:08:48 monk xscreensaver[85050]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 23:08:54 monk xscreensaver[85057]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 15 23:08:54 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Mar 15 23:17:01 monk CRON[85751]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 23:17:01 monk CRON[85751]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 15 23:30:01 monk CRON[86700]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 15 23:30:01 monk CRON[86700]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 16 00:17:01 monk CRON[88258]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 16 00:17:01 monk CRON[88258]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 16 00:37:00 monk systemd-logind[787]: Power key pressed.
Mar 16 10:45:53 monk systemd-logind[787]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Mar 16 10:46:06 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 10:46:06 monk xscreensaver[89349]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 10:46:10 monk xscreensaver[89355]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 10:46:11 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Mar 16 10:50:33 monk su: (to nobody) root on none
Mar 16 10:50:33 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Mar 16 10:50:34 monk systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Mar 16 10:50:35 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 16 10:50:35 monk su: (to nobody) root on none
Mar 16 10:50:35 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Mar 16 10:50:35 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 16 10:50:35 monk su: (to nobody) root on none
Mar 16 10:50:35 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Mar 16 10:53:46 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 16 10:53:56 monk systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 16 10:54:03 monk runuser: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user nobody by (uid=0)
Mar 16 10:54:55 monk runuser: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user nobody
Mar 16 11:08:37 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 11:08:37 monk xscreensaver[90443]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 11:08:42 monk xscreensaver[90451]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 11:08:42 monk unix_chkpwd[90451]: password check failed for user (guajardo)
Mar 16 11:08:42 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty=:0.0 ruser= rhost=  user=guajardo
Mar 16 11:08:44 monk xscreensaver[2070]: FAILED LOGIN 1 ON DISPLAY ":0.0", FOR "guajardo"
Mar 16 11:08:45 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 11:08:45 monk xscreensaver[90477]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 11:08:51 monk xscreensaver[90508]: pam_unix(xscreensaver:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 11:08:51 monk xscreensaver[2070]: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
Mar 16 11:17:02 monk CRON[90989]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 16 11:17:02 monk CRON[90989]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 16 11:30:01 monk CRON[91435]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 16 11:30:01 monk CRON[91435]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 16 12:17:01 monk CRON[93140]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 16 12:17:01 monk CRON[93140]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 16 12:30:01 monk CRON[93498]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 16 12:30:01 monk CRON[93498]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 16 13:04:48 monk pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar 16 13:04:48 monk pkexec[95326]: guajardo: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/] [COMMAND=/usr/sbin/xfpm-power-backlight-helper --set-brightness-switch 1]
Mar 16 13:04:49 monk slim: pam_unix(slim:session): session closed for user guajardo
Mar 16 13:04:51 monk polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:1 (system bus name :1.38, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Mar 16 13:05:04 monk slim: pam_unix(slim:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:05:09 monk systemd-logind[787]: Session 1 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Mar 16 13:05:11 monk slim: pam_unix(slim:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:05:11 monk slim: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Mar 16 13:05:11 monk slim: pam_unix(slim:session): session opened for user guajardo by (uid=0)
Mar 16 13:05:11 monk slim: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Mar 16 13:05:19 monk pkexec[96088]: guajardo: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/] [COMMAND=/usr/sbin/xfpm-power-backlight-helper --set-brightness-switch 0]
Mar 16 13:05:20 monk polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:1 (system bus name :1.1090 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
Mar 16 13:06:06 monk systemd-logind[787]: Power key pressed.
Mar 16 13:06:24 monk systemd-logind[787]: Power key pressed.
Mar 16 13:07:38 monk systemd-logind[787]: Power key pressed.
Mar 16 13:08:24 monk systemd-logind[787]: Power key pressed.
Mar 16 13:08:27 monk pkexec[96619]: guajardo: Error executing command as another user: Not authorized [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/] [COMMAND=/usr/sbin/xfpm-power-backlight-helper --set-brightness-switch 1]
Mar 16 13:08:27 monk slim: pam_unix(slim:session): session closed for user guajardo
Mar 16 13:08:27 monk polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:1 (system bus name :1.1090, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Mar 16 13:08:44 monk systemd-logind[787]: Power key pressed.
Mar 16 13:08:44 monk systemd-logind[787]: Powering Off...
Mar 16 13:08:44 monk systemd-logind[787]: System is powering down.
Mar 16 13:10:08 monk systemd-logind[768]: New seat seat0.
Mar 16 13:10:09 monk systemd-logind[768]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event4 (Power Button)
Mar 16 13:10:09 monk systemd-logind[768]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (Power Button)
Mar 16 13:10:09 monk systemd-logind[768]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Lid Switch)
Mar 16 13:10:09 monk systemd-logind[768]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event3 (Sleep Button)
Mar 16 13:10:09 monk systemd-logind[768]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
Mar 16 13:10:12 monk sshd[829]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mar 16 13:10:12 monk sshd[829]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mar 16 13:10:50 monk slim: pam_unix(slim:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:10:56 monk slim: pam_unix(slim:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:10:57 monk slim: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Mar 16 13:10:57 monk slim: pam_unix(slim:session): session opened for user guajardo by (uid=0)
Mar 16 13:10:57 monk systemd-logind[768]: New session 1 of user guajardo.
Mar 16 13:10:57 monk systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user guajardo by (uid=0)
Mar 16 13:11:14 monk pkexec: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar 16 13:11:14 monk pkexec[1985]: guajardo: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/] [COMMAND=/usr/sbin/xfpm-power-backlight-helper --set-brightness-switch 0]
Mar 16 13:11:23 monk polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:1 (system bus name :1.37 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
Mar 16 13:17:01 monk CRON[2798]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 16 13:17:01 monk CRON[2798]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 16 13:27:42 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:27:55 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:27:55 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=pts/2 ruser=guajardo rhost=  user=root
Mar 16 13:27:57 monk su: FAILED SU (to root) guajardo on pts/2
Mar 16 13:27:59 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:28:03 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:28:03 monk su: (to root) guajardo on pts/2
Mar 16 13:28:03 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar 16 13:30:01 monk CRON[3187]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar 16 13:30:01 monk CRON[3187]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Mar 16 13:35:41 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user root
Mar 16 13:36:06 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:36:10 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:36:10 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=0 tty=pts/2 ruser=guajardo rhost=  user=root
Mar 16 13:36:12 monk su: FAILED SU (to root) guajardo on pts/2
Mar 16 13:36:15 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:36:19 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:36:19 monk su: (to root) guajardo on pts/2
Mar 16 13:36:19 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
Mar 16 13:40:20 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:40:23 monk su: pam_unix(su:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Mar 16 13:40:23 monk su: (to root) guajardo on pts/1
Mar 16 13:40:23 monk su: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
```

Has anyone else had this issue? I couldn't find anything related nor similar here.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Screencap of the issue.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost a year later. You solve this by modifying `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` setting `KillUserProcesses=yes`. It still takes around 15 seconds to terminate all the processes of the session, but they stop and become available for the next user to log into X.